# Highlight active link from array

Tags: php, templates

I want to apply `class="active"` depending what page you on.  What the best way to do this?

For Example:

In the constructor function it create an array of links name and address.

```
class OrderController extends Controller {

   public $data = array();

   private __construct() {
        $this->data['sidebar'] = array(
            'New Orders' => '/admin/order',
            'Processing Orders' => '/admin/order/processing',
            'Completed Orders' => '/admin/order/completed',
    );


   public function actionIndex($status) {
        $data = $this->data;
        if ($status == "processing") {
         //how to apply class="active" when you on the order/processing page?
         //Apply active in the data['sidebar'] array 
        }

        $view = new view('orders.php', $data);
        $view->render();
    }
  }
```

The array passed into `actionIndex()` and render orders.php

In the orders.page, I have something like this:

```
<?php foreach ($sidebar as $name => $link): ?>
    <li>
      <strong><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a></strong>
   </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I want to add `class="active"` in the `li` tag.

Comment: Are you using URL rewriting by any chance?

Comment: first of all change `if ($tatus ==` ... to `if ($status ` . You've forgotten an **s** by **$tatus**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build on your array:

```
class OrderController extends Controller {

   public $data = array();

   private __construct() {
        $this->data['sidebar'] = array(
            'New Orders' => array( 'url'=>'/admin/order', 'class'=>'' ),
            'Processing Orders' => array( 'url'=>'/admin/order/processing', 'class'=>'' )
            'Completed Orders' => array( 'url'=>'/admin/order/completed', 'class'=>'' ),
    );


   public function actionIndex($status) {
        $data = $this->data;
        if ($status == "processing") {
          $data['sidebar']['Processing Orders']['class'] = 'active';
        }

        $view = new view('orders.php', $data);
        $view->render();
    }
  }
```

now you've to change your foreach:

```
<?php foreach ($sidebar as $name => $link): ?>
   <li class="<?php echo $link['class']; ?>">
      <strong><a href="<?php echo $link['url']; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a></strong>
   </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My basic idea is:

```
if ($tatus == "processing") {
    data['active'] = 'processing';
}
```

...........

```
<?php foreach ($sidebar as $name => $link): ?>
    <li <?php if ($active == $name) echo class="active"; ?>>
      <strong><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a></strong>
   </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The condition is based on name must be processing ... feel free to modify as needed.